# Does the first fundamental representation of $\frak{sp}_n$ generates all the other fundamental representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{sp_n}$ be the symplectic Lie algebra, that is, the $C_n$ complex simple Lie algebra. Is it true that the first fundamental, which is to say the vector space, representation $V_1$ of $\mathfrak{sp_n}$ generates all the other fundamental representations? By generates I mean that all other fundamental representations are contained in some tensor power $V_1^{\otimes k}$?

Comment: Yes. In fact, if $V_k$ (for $1\leq k\leq n$) denotes the $k$-th fundamental representation in the order of the nodes of the Dynkin diagram, and $V_0$ the trivial representation, then $\bigwedge^k V_1 = \bigoplus_{0\leq\ell\leq k,\;\ell\equiv k\pmod{2}} V_\ell$ (no multiplicities) for $0\leq k\leq n$. This is certainly well-known, but sadly I don't have a reference.

Comment: Ah, here's a reference: Fulton & Harris, *Representation Theory: A First Course* (Springer GTM **129**), theorem 17.5.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen: Thanks a lot for the answer and reference. If you put it as an answer then I can accept it.

Comment: (Of course, this is only talking about finite-dimensional repns...)

Comment: All irreducible algebraic representations of the symplectic group, full stop, are contained in some tensor power of $V_1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Copied from my own comments.)  Yes. In fact, if $V_k$ (for $1\leq k\leq n$) denotes the $k$-th fundamental representation in the order of the nodes of the Dynkin diagram, and $V_0$ the trivial representation, then for $0\leq k\leq n$ we have $$\bigwedge^k V_1 = \bigoplus_{0\leq\ell\leq k,\;\ell\equiv k\pmod{2}} V_\ell$$ (no multiplicities).  A possible reference is: : Fulton & Harris, *Representation Theory: A First Course* (Springer GTM **129**), theorem 17.5.